# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, hosting, putty

i have a website hosted in rackspace as of now i want to transfer the hosting to AWS, I created an instance with ubuntu OS.

I'm not able to connect with either putty or filezilla.

For Filezilla

- edit -> settings->SFTP add a ppk.

For Putty
-- first i load key through putty gen and download the private key 
-- add key on ssh->auth
-- and added host url, port 22 and click open it doesn't work

ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Note: I also tried with putty pageant to add a ppk key. But nothing works.

Help me out please it's been three days.

I tried all the possible solution which i got on web, something is wrong, please help me out
Thanks, In advance.
[image]

Comment: Have you added your public key to AWS?

Comment: You should never download a private key.  Instead, you should generate your own private key and upload the public key.

Comment: @PraveenP Hi praveen, no i have not, can you please tell me how ?

Comment: The error message means that you are using the wrong keypair. Did you download the keypair from the AWS Console when you created the keypair? If yes, then you need to convert the AWS keypair (which ends in .pem) to Putty's PPK format. Then use the PPK to connect to the instance. Tip: I use Bitvise which directly supports AWS keypairs and provides both a terminal window and a nice GUI for file transfer.

Comment: @PraveenP. This is good advice, but the OP has a chicken and egg situation. He needs to first login to the instance before he can change the authorized_keys. None of this can be done via the AWS console (except for upload your own public key - but then you have to create instances from the uploaded keypair). You cannot go back to an already created instance whithout doing some volume mounting magic.

Comment: @JohnHanley Now you mentioned, I understand the question better, thanks. But I don't think it's possible for OP to add key to an existing EC2 at all. Since AWS has no gui like DigitalOcean do, he'll have to recreate a new instance and mount the old EC2's volume to that. You can always ask AWS to mount the volume to a recovery system, but unless OP has a pair support plan I don't know what's the priority of no support plan user have.

Comment: AWS will not do that for you. There are documents on how to change EC2 keypairs. If you understand Linux, disk drives, volume mounting, it is quite simple to do. http://www.tothenew.com/blog/change-ssh-key-pair-of-running-ec2-instance/ I have written articles for Alibaba ECS keypairs on my website which is very similar to AWS.

Comment: @PraveenP - If you are an aspiring AWS Solutions Architect, I recommend going thru the process to replace keypairs and the process to create Linux users and upload keypairs to EC2. You never know when a client (or yourself) will have an emergency.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the AWS Console using your Root account (email address) then click your name on the top right. Then select **My Security Credentials** and (if prompted click **Continue to Security Credentials**) and select **Users** on the left(check below the line on how to create IAM user), then click on the IAM account name, then **Security Credentials** tab and scroll down and click **Upload SSH public key**. Pase the public key and click **Upload SSH public key**.

Now login as that IAM account and create the EC2 Instance and you should be able to SSH to it.

---

If you haven't created an IAM account follow the below steps :
Login to Root account (email address) then click your name on the top right corner. Select **My Security Credentials** and click **Get Started with IAM Users**.
Once you're in the User tab, click Add user at the top and give yourself a name. Then tick both **Programmatic access** and **AWS Management Console access**. Then select **Custom password** option and set a password.

Untick the **Require password reset**. Then lick **Next: Permissions**, select **Attach existing policy directly** and select **AmazonEC2FullAccess** (user the search filter than scrolling). Then click **Next** and click **Create**.

Now download the Credentials with **Download .csv**, then click close at the bottom.

Comment: By the way, I don't think it'll let you add a public key to the Root account. So you gonna have to use IAM account one way or another.

Comment: This will not work with EC2 instances to connect via SSH.

Comment: Have you created a new EC2 instance with that key? You can't change stuff on existing EC2 from console.